# Azure Board app integration with MSteams - Retrospective board is not visible in MSTeam when i added the Azure app

Tags: azure, azure-devops, microsoft-teams, azure-boards

Azure Board app integration with MSteams - Retrospective board is not visible in MSTeam when I added the Azure app. Please can someone help here.
I am trying to get the retrospective board in the teams

Comment: Have you had a chance to check the provided solution?

Answer (score 0):

The Azure DevOps Services tabs in Microsoft Teams only supports adding a dashboard or Kanban board as of today as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Azure DevOps Service Tabs]

For viewing your Team's Retrospective board on Teams, you can embed the board's Azure DevOps URL inside a Teams tab using the native tab website functionality.

[image: Website Functionality on Microsoft Teams]

Once configured, it would look something like the following:

[image: Retrospective Tab on Microsoft Teams]